# Não consigo fazer com que ele imprima tudo junto como um vetor, ele fica tudo separado

Tags: javascript, html, array

P1-2017-RAD I

```
    <table>
      <tr>
          <th>Veculos</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody id="veiculos">
      </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
<script>
    var cadastro = new function(){
        this.veiculos = [];
        this.el = document.getElementById("veiculos");
        this.itemEditar = -1;

        this.listarTodos = function(){
            var dados = '';

            if(this.veiculos.length > 0){
                for(i=0;i<this.veiculos.length;i++){
                    dados += '<tr>';
                    dados += '<td>'+this.veiculos[i]+'</td>';
                    dados += '<td><button onclick="cadastro.alterar('+i+')"> Alterar </button></td>';
                    dados += '<td><button onclick="cadastro.excluir('+i+')"> Excluir </button></td>';
                    dados += '</tr>';
                }
            }
            this.el.innerHTML = dados;
        };

        this.add = function(){
            var id;
            id++;
            var placa = document.getElementById("add-placa").value;
            var marca = document.getElementById("add-marca").value;
            var modelo = document.getElementById("add-modelo").value;

            if(placa && marca && modelo){
                if(this.itemEditar == -1){
                    this.veiculos.push(id,placa,marca,modelo);
                    /*this.veiculos.push(id);
                    this.veiculos.push(placa);
                    this.veiculos.push(marca);
                    this.veiculos.push(modelo);
                    */
                }else{
                    this.veiculos.splice(this.itemEditar,1,id,placa.trim(),marca.trim(),modelo.trim());
                    /*this.veiculos.splice(this.itemEditar,1,id);
                    this.veiculos.splice(this.itemEditar,2,placa.trim());
                    this.veiculos.splice(this.itemEditar,3,marca.trim());
                    this.veiculos.splice(this.itemEditar,4,modelo.trim());*/
                    this.itemEditar = -1;
                }
                this.listarTodos();
            }   
            this.novo();
        };

        this.editar = function(item){
            this.itemEditar = item;
            var placa = this.veiculos[item];
            var marca = this.veiculos[item];
            var modelo = this.veiculos[item];
            if(placa && marca && modelo){
                var elPlaca = document.getElementById("add-placa");
                var elMarca = document.getElementById("add-marca");
                var elModelo = document.getElementById("add-modelo");
                elPlaca.value = placa;
                elMarca.value = marca;
                elModelo.value = modelo;
            }
        };

        this.novo = function(){
            this.itemEditar = -1;
            var elId;
            var elMarca = document.getElementById("add-marca");
            var elPlaca = document.getElementById("add-placa");
            var elModelo = document.getElementById("add-modelo");

            elId.value = this.elId + 1;
            elMarca.value = '';
            elPlaca.value = '';
            elModelo.value = '';
        };

        this.excluir = function(item){
            this.veiculos.splice(item,1);
            this.listarTodos();
        };

    }
    function fechar(){
        document.getElementById("mostrar").style.display = 'none';
    };
    cadastro.listarTodos();
</script>
```

[image: ---]

Por exemplo, eu queria que ele imprimisse assim:

ID: 1           Placa: Hsv-2536       Marca: Fiat        Modelo: Uno

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do que tem `this.veiculos`?

Comment: o this.veiculos seria o vetor, e nele deveria estar dentro [id,placa,marca,modelo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vêz de

```
dados += '<td>'+this.veiculos[i]+'</td>';
```

precisas de um `<td>` para cada elemento dessa array `this.veiculos[i]`, e podes fazer isso assim:

```
dados += this.veiculos[i].reduce(function(str, el){
    return str + '<td>' + el + '</td>';
}, '');
```

Assim cada elemento da array `[id,placa,marca,modelo]` vai ser colocado dentro da sua `td`, e o `reduce` retorna uma *string* com tudo.

Se `this.veiculos[i]` fôr um objeto, podes fazer assim:

```
dados += Object.keys(this.veiculos[i]).reduce(function(str, chave){
    return str + '<td>' + this.veiculos[i][chave] + '</td>';
}, '');
```

Comment: eu testei e deu esse erro aqui: Uncaught TypeError: this.veiculos[i].reduce is not a function

Comment: @AntonyGabriel ok, nesse caso `this.veiculos[i]` não é uma array como indicaste, talvez um json. O que dá `console.log(typeof this.veiculos[i], this.veiculos[i]);`?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: this.veiculos[i].reduce is not a function
    at Object.listarTodos (p1-rad1-RE_UP.html:38)
    at Object.add (p1-rad1-RE_UP.html:74)
    at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit (p1-rad1-RE_UP.html:7). Isso aqui

Comment: Coloca esse `console.log` que pedi na linha depois de `for(i=0;i<this.veiculos.length;i++){`

Comment: o erro continua

Comment: @AntonyGabriel essa linha com o console.log não tira o erro, é para eu saber que tipo de conteúdo tens. Sabes o que faz console.log? coloca o seu resultado aqui pf.

Comment: @AntonyGabriel conseguiste?

Comment: sim, consegui imprimir tudo, o problema é a pesquisa pela placa, eu fiz uma nova pergunta, olha lá

Comment: @AntonyGabriel vi a outra pergunta agora e vi que o que tinhas não era um array, mas sim um objeto, dá uma olhada a esta resposta aqui agora.